# Heroku redis/sidekiq Connection timed out - user specified timeout error

Tags: heroku, redis, sidekiq

This is an issue that **happened after upgrading my Redis instance version on Heroku** using `heroku redis:upgrade`
The error happened when Sidekiq tried to connect to Redis:

```
Connection timed out - user specified timeout
```

After reading this guide:
https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Using-Redis#life-in-the-cloud
I thought the problem might be in the network connection, so I tried increasing the network timeout in `config/initializers/sidekiq.rb` like this:
`config.redis = { network_timeout: 5 }`

Unfortunately this did not help, it only increased the time that it takes to create the connection, but the same error was still occurring in the end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I noticed that after upgrading the Redis instance version, Heroku had not updated the `REDIS_URL` config var to match the new redis url.
So, the URL in the config var:

```
heroku config:get REDIS_URL
```

was different from the one returned by:

```
heroku redis:credentials
```

So my solution was as per the following guide:
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/managing-heroku-redis-using-cli#redis-credentials
to reset Redis the credentials:

```
heroku redis:credentials --reset
```

With this command, new credentials are created for the Redis instance and the related config vars on the Heroku application are automatically updated.